# Llamar a un menu especifico segun el nombre de cada pagina en WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy haciendo una pagina en WP y la idea es que al seleccionar la pagina "lavadoras", pasarle una condicion a un widget para que muestre el menu "menu lavadoras" dentro de la pagina single.php. Hay un menu creado para cada pagina "secadoras", "microondas", "planchas", etc. La idea es poder mostrar un menu diferente en base a eso.

```
<div id="single-post" class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <h1>Caracteristicas y partes de <?php the_title() ?></h1>
        <div class="col">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div id="item-image" class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail("large"); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como uso  para obtener el nombre de la pagina pensaba en que de una manera similar podria usarlo para llamar a estos menus, no tengo claros los parametros que podrian identificar cada menu.

```
function add_menu_type(){
register_sidebar(
   array(
     'menu' => 'lavadoras',
     'container' => 'div',
     'before_widget' => '',
     'after_widget' => ''
   ) ); }
 add_action("widgets_init", "add_menu_type");
```

El detalle es que no logro llamar al menu especifico.
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varias formas de resolver este problema, sin embargo puedes hacerlo de una forma simple, nombrando a ambos de la misma forma, por ejemplo, digamos que tienes una Página o Post llamado "Lavadoras", entonces en tus Menus de WordPress puedes crear un menu llamado "Lavadoras", tiene que tener exactamente el mismo nombre de la página, por lo que basado en ese nombre puedes hacer la siguiente consulta.

```
$post_title = get_the_title();
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'          => $post_title,
    'menu_class'    => 'wp-menu-nav',
) );
```

De esta forma no tienes que crear un widget por cada pagina, pero si un menú por cada una, solo pon el código en el single o page segun necesites, esto usa `wp_nav_menu()` Para obtener un Menú cuyo nombre sea el de la pagina.

Como dije existen muchas formas de hacerlo, personalmente te recomiendo explorar el Plugin `ACF Awesome Custom Fields` y descubrir un poco más sobre el core de WordPress para que encuentres formas más elegantes de hacer esta tarea.

Comment: Gracias @jefferzon me ha venido genial y lo resolvi con eso, me gusta lo del Plugin ACF Awesome Custom Fields, lo usare para una segunda version del mismo ecommerce.